# Material Design Lite Switch not working on jquery load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, material-design

I am trying to load MDL Switch through external file but it's not working.

Here is my main page code : index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="material.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="lo">Load</a>
<div class="demo-switch">

<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-2">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch-2" class="mdl-switch__input" />
<span class="mdl-switch__label">Bluetooth</span>
</label>

</div>

<script src="js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.getScript("js/material.min.js").done(function(){

      $(document).on("click",".lo",function(){
      $('.demo-switch').load("new_test.php");
      });
  });



});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is file new_test.php

```
<div class="demo-switch">

<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-2">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch-2" class="mdl-switch__input" />
<span class="mdl-switch__label">Bluetooth</span>
</label>

</div>
```

Here are the result after i press load button:

[image: Here are the result after i press load button]

possible js is not working properly but i can't find a way to fix this.
please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Will need to call **componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()** for dynamic dom.

Answer (score 1):

Add `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()` at the very bottom of your view (new_test.php, in this case).